# How Can I reset a persisted tree fancytree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancytree

Basically I'm using tree with persistent mean when I expand the node and then refresh the page the expanded nodes still shows as expended. 
but I have button to reset the tree which will move the tree to its unexpanded form. 
My question is how can is reset the tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `clearPersistData` method:
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtPersist#methods